# Why does this switch statement not match substrings?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am trying to match substring of a string variable with a switch statement:

```
#$value = "55"
#$value = "55-"
#$value = "55+"
$value = "+55"

switch ($Value) {
    "^\+" {"Starts With +"}
    "^\d" {"Starts With a digit"}

    "+$" {"Ends with +"}
    "-$" {"Ends with -"}
}
```

The switch statement will not trigger. Even if I do `"^\+.*" {"Starts With +"}`. I really need to partially match the contents of `$Value`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens as `switch` [doesn't expect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3) a regex per default. To use regular expressions for matching, pass `-regex` for the statement. Like so,

```
 $value = "+55"
 switch -regex ($Value) {
     "^\+" {"Starts With +"}
     "^\d" {"Starts With a digit"}     
     "\+$" {"Ends with +"} #Remember to escape quantifier
     "-$" {"Ends with -"}
     default {"no match"}
 }
# Output
Starts With +
```